# Does postgresql recreate index when adding new data to the column?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have an sql table foo created like below

#### Create table

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo(id INTEGER, name TEXT) ;
```

#### Inserted some data

```sql
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1, 'Alex');
```

#### Created INDEX

```sql
CREATE INDEX bar_idx ON foo(id) ;
```

#### Now Inserted some extra data

```sql
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1, 'Bob');
```

Does it automatically updatae previously created index in the column ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indexes are always kept up-to-date. In the event of bulk changes of a very large number of rows you may want to run [REINDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html) but that is not normally necessary.

Comment: I would not recommend `REINDEX`, unless pgstattuple shows that the index is in very bad shape.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this index get updated by postgresql automatically whenever you add a new row.

In your case, your index i.e. `bar_idx` will be updated when you will add data/new row in the table.

When there are significant data updates, you may need to use *REINDEX*, but in you case i.e. inserting a single row, there is no need of it.

Answer (score 0):

- **No**, PostgreSQL does not recreate the index when adding new data to a column.
- Instead, it **updates** the index to include the new data. This is done automatically by PostgreSQL and does not require any manual intervention.
- When you insert new data into a table, PostgreSQL will **automatically** update any indexes on the table to include the new data. This ensures that the index remains **up-to-date** and can be used to efficiently search for data in the table.

Answer (score -1):

yes if you simply enter data then it will be update but if you insert another row then
You need to explicitly  rebuild or reorganise the index to ensure that it reflects the current state of the data.(for better practise)

In your example as you created an index on 'id' attribute and later when you inserted another row the index will now be updated

you have to use REINDEX bar_idx;

while it is not necessary to run this